# 2D point rotation based off a matrix

Tags: java, math, matrix, rotation

I have a 6x6 matrix, with key points as G's and empty points as hyphens. (The O's and L's are irrelevant to this question. Note that the numbers accross the side and top and the hyphen in the top left are only to label the axes.)

```
// Original Matrix
- 012345
0 ----G-
1 ----L-
2 ----L-
3 ----L-
4 GOOOL-
5 ------
```

By using the following two methods, I am able to rotate the above matrix by 90 degrees to the left.

```
public static void transpose(int[][] m) {
    for (int x = 0; x < m.length; x++) {
        for (int y = x; y < m[0].length; y++) {
            int temp = m[x][y];
            m[x][y] = m[y][x];
            m[y][x] = temp;
        }
    }
}

public static void swapRows(int[][] m) {
    for (int i = 0, k = m.length - 1; i < k; ++i, --k) {
        int[] x = m[i];
        m[i] = m[k];
        m[k] = x;
    }
}
```

Swapping the rows, followed by transposing the rows, results in the following matrix. (180 Degree rotation included for following explanation)

```
// Rotated -90° Matrix    // Rotated 180° Matrix
- 012345                  - 012345
0 ------                  0 ------
1 GLLLL-                  1 -LOOOG
2 ----O-                  2 -L----
3 ----O-                  3 -O----
4 ----O-                  4 -O----
5 ----G-                  5 -G----
```

In code, I also have a ArrayList of java.awt.Point's which store the position of the G points. Once the matrix is rotated, those points must be updated. I could scan the array for the G points, although each point must keep the same index in the ArrayList, and regardless of any way it is scanned, there is no guarantee that the index of the first point in the original matrix will remain in the same index as the first point in the 90 Degree or 180 Degree matrix.

For the ArrayList of

```
public ArrayList<java.awt.Point> keyPoints = new ArrayList<>();
keyPoints.add(new Point(0, 4));
keyPoints.add(new Point(4, 0));
```

I currently have this method in place for rotation the points.
It is based of the following equation.

[image: Matrix Rotation Equation]

```
for (int i = 0; i < keyPoint.size(); i++) {
    Point p = keyPoint.get(i);
    double angle = Math.toRadians(-90);
    double cos = Math.cos(angle);
    double sin = Math.sin(angle);
    double x = (p.x * cos) - (p.y * sin);
    double y = (p.x * sin) + (p.y * cos);
    keyPoint.set(i, new Point((int) x, (int) y));
    System.out.printf("Point: (%.2f, %.2f)\n", x, y);
}
```

For the 90 degree rotation, The output I am currently getting is as follows

```
Point: (4.00, 0.00)
Point: (0.00, -4.00)
```

Although for the 90°, the output I am looking for is

```
Point: (0.00, 1.00)
Point: (4.00, 5.00)
```

Is there any suggestions you can give as to the implementation of my for loop, (if not a better solution altogether)?

Comment: Do you want to rotate by angles other than 90*n?

Comment: All rotations are 90*n. Due to my matrix setup, I don't believe rotations outside of 90*n are possible.

Comment: So you'd better to set up some tables with -1/0/1 instead of sin/cos calculations.

Comment: @MBo Would that only affect the speed of the calculation, or does it serve any other purpose?

Comment: both speed and clarity (I hope) - you can see something like Table90 in code. Look at my answer edit. That approach works in-place, and may use functions like G90 etc

Answer (score 0):

You have used equations for rotation about coordinate origin (0,0).

If you want to rotate about arbitrary center (cx, cy) (middle of matrix in your case, I think), then equations are:

```
 x' = cx + (x-cx) * Cos(theta) - (y-cy) * Sin(theta)
 y' = cy + (x-cx) * Sin(theta) + (y-cy) * Cos(theta)
```

Edit:
There is yet another method to transform matrix in-place:
Given: function F that maps some coordinate (x,y) to new coordinate (x',y')
Find inverse function `G=Inverse(F)` that for given destination (x',y') finds  source coordinates (x,y) 
Walk for matrix coordinates i,j
Extract `Element[i,j]`
Find `i',j' = G(i,j)`
Copy `Element[i',j']` to i,j coordinates
Repeat for i'j' until return to i,j occurs (4 or 2 cycles)
Copy extracted `Element[i,j]` to the final place

Example: mirror about vertical axis

```
G(x,y) = (n-1-x, y)
extract R=A[0,0]
G(0,0) = n-1,0
copy A[n-1,0] to A[0,0] 
G(n-1,0) = 0,0        //start coordinate reached
copy R to A[n-1, 0]
do the same for all x<n/2
```